# Drawing huge amount of 2D data on .NET

Tags: .net, graphics, visualization

There is a need to visualize large quantity of 2d graphic objects (draw some schema of complex structure) using .NET framework - for example 10-20 thousand primitives on one canvas. Assume we have respective hardware - powerful server PC with multi-core CPU, huge amount of RAM and some recent videocard. According to books and MSDN the solution is to use WPF with its hardware acceleration, particularly Drawings subsystem. I've implemented simple scenario with GeometryDrawings and VisualHost and it is pretty decent, but there is a problem - visualized objects also need to have changing state (i.e. quickly change color without redrawing) and accept mouse events (click, drag'n'drop) which Freezables doesn't support as they are no Framework Elements. Any ideas how to solve the problem most efficiently? Our graphical object looks very much alike framework-supplied Shape and its descendants, but it surely won't match performance requirements. 
* edit * 
Graphic objects can have as simple structure (red rectangle) as complex (multiple nested objects that contains Paths - random-shaped curves). Objects may overlap. Layering (hide and show specific objects at some particular moment) may be implemented later as additional feature. State change may occur once every 2-5 seconds, triggered by external event.

Comment: More detail would help.  How big are your 10k primitives?  What screen resolution?  Do they overlap?  Are all of them always visible (or hidden underneath others?)

Comment: I have drawn moving graph with plotted lines >10000 observations in a `picturebox` and it works perfectly even with mouse events to highlight specific lines clicked. Have you tried it out on `picturebox`?

Comment: Edited question providing additional details.

Comment: If you maintain the hierarchy order of graphical objects and you have bitmap images at certain points (down the 20k primitives), then you can load the bitmap (even save it in files if memory is of concern) and do the graphical events on top of that to reduce the time for painting the unchanged portion of the graphics - Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: **shaders.**

[This looks like a decent tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71617/Getting-Started-with-Shader-Effects-in-WPF) on using shaders in WPF. Pixel and Vertex shaders themselves are pretty simple for drawing primitives.

A shader will let you take full advantage of hardware acceleration. On a decent GPU, 10k primitives is nothing.

Changing colors, etc. on a frame-to-frame basis is trivial in this context.

Most of the shader tutorials are for 3D, but they're applicable to 2D as well.

You could also have a look at XNA. It doesn't natively support putting a DirectX context inside of a WPF or Winforms window, but there are quite a few tutorials on that as well. XNA is pretty powerful and takes care of a lot of the boilerplate code like matrix manipulation, etc. that you'll need. Even if you decide not to go with XNA, the tutorials on [create.msdn.com](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) can be very educational.

**Update 10/2012**

XNA is effectively dead, but there are quite a few examples out there of using shaders in WPF. If your C++ skills are up to snuff, you can use the [D3DImage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx) to place a Direct3D window on your WPF form. The XNA samples are still valuable for their shader content and high-level approach to graphics development.

If you were excited about XNA, have a look at [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com), which is coming along nicely. I'm using it successfully for some cross-platform 3D stuff (Win7, OSX, iOS) and have no complaints.

Comment: I don't know that I would say that XNA does not 'natively' support inclusion in WinForms or WPF - I've made a couple of custom XNA-based components which I drop into a winforms application like any other.  There was nothing tricky involved - in my case the component inherited `Panel` and was filled with an XNA viewport.

Comment: @J... I've done it, but it required some work. Not a huge amount but I didn't want to err the expectation that it was just drag & drop.

Comment: Interesting... Will look and try this approach. The only thing bothers me if objects drawn by shader effects would support user input (i.e. mouse events).

Comment: @Jaded you'd have to handle that separately. There are a lot of tricks you can use for that, though. Are we talking line drawings or filled shapes?

Answer (score 0):

If you need detailed control over how drawing is done and what regions are redrawn, go with GDI+ (used by WinForms).

You can use GDI+ to draw into a Bitmap objects and you can redraw arbitrary parts of it when it has changed.

AFAIK GDI+ is not hardware accelerated, so I'd do a quick benchmark. My feeling is it will be faster in your case.

Comment: Will consider as backup solution. Application's platform is mainly Windows 7, so WinForms will look ugly there.